# Does consistency of a test imply continuity of a preorder?

Tags: probability, general-topology, order-theory

Let $F$ and $G$ be two real-valued probability distributions, considered as cadlag functions with the uniform norm [not the Skorohod metric], and let $\mathbb{F}_n$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ be empirical distributions of samples of size $n$ from $F$ and $m$ from $G$.  If $\preceq$ is a continuous total preorder, the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem shows that $F\prec G$ implies $P(\mathbb{F}_n\prec\mathbb{G}_m)\to 1$. That is, continuity of the preorder implies consistency of the test

Is the converse true? That is, from consistency of the test, $F\prec G$ implies $P(\mathbb{F}_n\prec\mathbb{G}_m)\to 1$, can we deduce continuity of the preorder? This wouldn't be true for the Skorohod metric, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample with the uniform norm.

Answer (score 0):

After more work: the converse isn't true.

A simple counterexample is the preorder based on the supremum of the support of the distribution.  This is not continuous, but is consistent.

Unfortunately this is not a counterexample to the underlying question about the relationship between consistency and the existence of a utility representation.